# TCL parsing a list of arguments to an external call

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcl

Im trying to execute a call to a python script through aldec riviera-pro

my call is `python $python_app_name $python_app_args` However my `$python_app_args` are passed as a single string and not multiple strings resulting in that the python application only sees it as one argument and its execution fails.

I've tried I think all methods to pass this in various ways however with same result. 
Do i really need to put each argument into a single variable for this to work?

I also tried to use array but i keep getting the

```
can't set "python_string_args(0)": variable isn't array
```

MY code for the array assignment looks at follows

```
set python_string_args(0) "-gr"
set python_string_args(1) "-l"
set python_string_args(2) "-r sim"
set python_string_args(3) "-t config_arc_cnt_acc.cfg"
```

IE I have workaround fx i could just assign them to each its own value or i could make the python application split the string into its components based on the argument knowledge.

**note**
The `python` command in riviera-pro calls the external python program installed in python/python34 which is the same as when I just executes the script from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if the Tcl interpreter in your system is recent. If it is, you should be able to use

```
python $python_app_name {*}$python_app_args
```

to get the arguments as separate strings. The `{*}` prefix is a syntactic modifier that splices the items in a list as separate arguments. Example:

```
list a {b c d} e
# -> {a {b c d} e}
list a {*}{b c d} e
# -> {a b c d e}
```

The documentation is on the man page for Tcl syntax, link below.

In older versions, this might work:

```
eval python $python_app_name $python_app_args
```

but that might make undesirable adjustments to the arguments. Try printing

```
puts [concat python $python_app_name $python_app_args]
```

to see if that looks like a sensible command line.

You won't be able to pass an array as a value, arrays don't work that way.

Documentation: [concat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/concat.htm), [eval](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/eval.htm), [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [puts](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/puts.htm), [{*}](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/Tcl.htm)

Comment: This works `{*}$python_app_args`. But why what does `{*}`. cant seem to find a reference to this syntax.